# Should I remove some independent features based on PCA?

Tags: classification, correlation, pca, random-forest, svm

I am quite new to machine learning and just got started on classification. My Class is either positive or negative for around 400 genes. I performed a PCA analysis in R to figure out how my independent features are interacting and this is the output I got. Some of the features like expression1_1.1, expression1_1.2, and expression2_1.1 seem to be highly correlated, as they are just superimposed on each other. Should I remove some of these features before I start my random forest/SVM/neural net classifier? How can I interpret this graph?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why would you do that? The point of PCA is dimensionality reduction, not variable selection. You can obtain new variables which are linear combinations of your original variables which are uncorrelated, so why not use that?

Comment: Okay, I will look into doing that! In general, is having highly correlated features bad for prediction?

Comment: For prediction no, not necessarily. For interpretation... probably (but also not necessarily).

Comment: PCA by definition finds independent components. What you are seeing in the plot should be the loadings on your genes, which in turn seem to be correlated. I think you shouldn't cut correlated genes, ad do as suggested in the previous comment. I would add that you can drop some PCs instead, maybe keeping the ones that together explain at least 95% of your variance, or checking the elbow plot. In that way, you keep the most relevant "meta-genes" and maybe lower your risk of overfitting.

Comment: From your comments, when predicting on a new dataset, should I use PCA on the whole new dataset and reduce the number of PCs based on the amount of variance (like 97%) and give this PC information (1:9 perhaps) to the random forest model to predict on instead of actual expression values? @user2974951

Comment: Not on the whole data set, PCA if done should be done only on the training set. Then you transform your test set using this trained PCA.